# How to display querysets in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I write a functiın and the final, function creates several model objects (same model different values). I listed these objects but I want to list just one time with the same `dashboard_id` value.
I found something about that but I have an issue with displaying in the table.

It is working but does not display the values. How can I solve it?

**views.py**

```
def reports_list(request):
    report_list = Reports.objects.values_list('dashboard_id', flat=True).distinct()
    context = {
        'report_list': report_list,
    }
    return render(request, "report_list.html", context)
```

**report_list.html**

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Kullanıcı</th>
         <th>Yüklenme Tarihi</th>
         <th>Görüntüle</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {%  for report in report_list %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{ report.user.first_name }} {{ report.user.last_name }}</td>
         <td>{{ report.created_at }}</td>
         <td>view</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

to be clear:
[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you have in your function corresponds with what I see as your intention in the template. Therefore you can try this instead:

```
   def reports_list(request, dashboard_id):
        report_list = Reports.objects.filter(dashboard_id=dashboard_id).all()
        context = {
            'report_list': report_list,
        }
        return render(request, "report_list.html", context=context)
```

If you think your original function is correct, then you have forgotten to add the context (`context=context`).